# how can i create constraint on table based on many column and value in another table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

i have atable such as codes table have these values:

| Major_code | minor_code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Country |
| 1 | 1 | USA |
| 1 | 2 | JOR |
| 2 | 0 | Food |
| 2 | 1 | Burger |
| 2 | 2 | Mansaf |

I need to create table have these columns (ID, Country_ID , Food_ID) what is the best constraint that resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not clear how this "value in another table" fits in. An example would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Having a single lookup table for all reference codes is a very poor design, to the point of almost being a SQL anti-pattern. It is likely to have performance issues. It is also difficult to ensure that the value of COUNTRY_MINOR_CODE references an actual country minor code in the reference table. Which brings us to this statement:

> I need to create table have these columns (ID, Country_ID , Food_ID)

Can't be done. Or at least it can be done but you can't build foreign keys on that, because minor keys are not unique in the referenced table. But if you are set on a single table, say `lookup_table` with primary key defined on `(major_code, minor code)`, you need this:

```
create table country_food (
 id                 number primary_key
,country_major_code number not null
,country_minor_code number not null
,food_major_code    number not null
,food_minor_code    number not null
,constraint country_major_code_ck check (country_major_code = 1)
,constraint country_minor_code_ck check (country_minor_code != 0)
,constraint food_major_code_ck    check (country_major_code = 2)
,constraint food_minor_code_ck    check (country_minor_code != 0)
,constraint country_code_fk foreign key (country_major_code, country_minor_code) references lookup_table
,constraint food_code_fk foreign key (food_major_code, food_minor_code) references lookup_table
)
/
```

The hard coding of values, the additional check constraints, the increased complexity of joining to look up the `name` ... These are all reasons why you should choose to have separate tables for FOOD, COUNTRY, etc.

```
create table country (
 country_id    number       primary_key
,country_name  varchar2(24) not null 
)
/
create table food (
 food_id    number primary_key
,food_name  varchar2(24) not null 
)
/
create table country_food (
 id                 number primary_key
,country_id         number not null
,food_id            number not null
,food_major_code    number not null
,constraint country_code_fk foreign key (country_id) references country
,constraint food_code_fk foreign key (food_id) references food
)
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right, you can get all Country+Food pairs with the query

```
select t1.minor_code counrty_id, t2.minor_code food_id
from (
    select minor_code
    from  codesTable
    where Major_code = (
        select c.Major_code 
        from  codesTable c
        where c.minor_code=0 and c.name='Country') 
) t1
cross join (
    select minor_code
    from  codesTable
    where Major_code = (
        select c.Major_code 
        from  codesTable c
        where c.minor_code=0 and c.name='Food') 
) t2
```

You can use the query to insert data into a table with an autogenerated ID or use it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to consider the design of the tables

1. Table of country
2. Table of foods
3. Tables of food_country -------- relationship => **many-to-many**

```html
CREATE TABLE Country
( 
  Major_code numeric(15) not null,
  minor_code numeric(15),
  name varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT country_pk PRIMARY KEY (Major_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Food
( 
  Food_ID numeric(15) not null,
  //...........................
  name varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT food_pk PRIMARY KEY (Food_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Counry_Food
( 
  ID numeric(10) not null,
  Country_ID numeric(15) not null,
  Food_ID numeric(15) not null,
  CONSTRAINT fk_country
    FOREIGN KEY (Country_ID)
    REFERENCES Country(Major_code),
  CONSTRAINT fk_food
    FOREIGN KEY (Food_ID)
    REFERENCES supplier(Food_ID),
);
```